# How to write trigger body in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-delete

I'm confused how a trigger in SQL Server knows what event fired the trigger and what to do.

For example I have a trigger that update on table A and it is performing `AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE`. Now my question is how I make the body to perform each task when it triggered, do I need to make separate triggers for each task or is it a way to specify what it needs to do for each task on a single body and a single trigger. And if it is okay can anybody give some explanation and example for it

Thanks

Comment: You *can* figure out which operation was the reason for the trigger to fire - but I find this very annoying and hard to write (and read / maintain) code. I **much prefer** to have three separate triggers - one for each operation - then it's **very clear** from the get-go what caused the trigger to fire - no guessing, no messy code .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** must do a single trigger - this is the logic needed to keep the three operation - `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` - apart:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.YourTriggerName
ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- check if both the Inserted as well as the Deleted pseudo tables exist
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted)
    BEGIN
        -- trigger operation : UPDATE
        -- "Inserted" contains the new values for the rows after the update
        -- "Deleted" contains the old values for the rows before the update
    END

    -- check if only the Inserted pseudo tables exists
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted)
    BEGIN
        -- trigger operation: INSERT
        -- "Inserted" contains the values for the rows inserted 
    END

    -- check if only the Deleted pseudo tables exists
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted)
    BEGIN
        -- trigger operation: DELETE
        -- "Deleted" contains the values for the rows having been deleted
    END
END;
```

**BE AWARE:** the trigger is called **once per statement** - not once per row - so the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables will potentially **contain multiple rows** - handle them in a **set-based manner**, as tables - don't do anything like

```
SELECT @ID = i.ID FROM Inserted i
```

This will **NOT WORK** for multiple rows being inserted at once in a single SQL statement!

But as I said - this is a bit messy, makes for a really large trigger, and makes it hard to maintain this code. I'd personally would **much rather** have three separate, focused triggers - one for each of the operations you need to handle.